# How to install boruta in conda?

Tags: python, feature-selection, anaconda

I want to install boruta in my anaconda environment, but if I execute

```
conda install boruta
```

It displays:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - boruta

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

I guess I could install it using the `pip` that belongs to the Anaconda environment, but I am not sure if that is the best way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the instructions at both [Github](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py#how-to-install) and [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/boruta_py), you should try

```
 conda install -c conda-forge boruta_py
```